# Subtable title with knitr::kables

Tags: r, r-markdown, knitr, kable

I am constructing a document with Rmarkdown that has some complicated 2-part tables. I am assembling the 2-part tables using `knitr::kables`, but I would like to add a subtitle to each part. For example, I would like to do something along the lines of

```r
df1 = data.frame(id=1:3,name=letters[1:3])
df2 = data.frame(id=4:6,name=letters[4:6])
knitr::kables(list(knitr::kable(df1,caption="header1"),
                   knitr::kable(df2,caption="header2")),
              caption="Overall header")
```

And have it display `header1` at the top of the first subtable and `header2` at the top of the second subtable. However, this does not work for me.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Maybe this helps?

````
---
output: html_document
---


```{r}
library(kableExtra)
df1 = data.frame(id=1:3,name=letters[1:3])
df2 = data.frame(id=4:6,name=letters[4:6])

x <- knitr::kable(df1) |> add_header_above(c("HEADER 1"=2))

y <- knitr::kable(df2) |> add_header_above(c("HEADER 2"=2))


knitr::kables(list(x, y)) |> add_header_above(c("Overall header" = 2))
```
````

If it is also an option to change to quarto, there it works like a charm, e.g.

````
---
format: html
---

```{r}
#| label: tbl-example
#| tbl-cap: "Overall header"
#| tbl-subcap: 
#|   - "Header1"
#|   - "Header2"
#| layout-ncol: 2

library(knitr)
df1 = data.frame(id=1:3,name=letters[1:3])
df2 = data.frame(id=4:6,name=letters[4:6])
kable(head(df1))
kable(head(df2))
```
````

[image]

Comment: Thanks, this is helpful. I had already identified the `add_header_above` solution, though it isn't nearly as attractive as the Quarto output. Unfortunately, Quarto isn't an option as we are using special LaTeX templates only available in Rmarkdown.

Comment: Did add_header_above solved your problem?

Comment: Yes and no. It does produce something that is workable, but not particularly attractive when you are stacking tables one on top of the other. But it is the best solution I have found so far outside of Quarto (that I can't use as explained above).